# How can you input and display a radical in a computer text document?

Tags: radicals, input-method

(I apologize if this question is off-topic on Japanese.SE or is more suitable for SuperUser).

I like to write computer notes about what I learn in Japanese. From time to time, I would like to be able to include in my text a given radical, say kokoro **心**, which takes several graphic forms when used as an element in a more complex kanji, for instance .

I did not succeed on my system (Mac OS X 10.7) to find the glyphs for these variants exactly as I would like them (I would also be interested about how to do this on Windows 7 or Linux).

I first tried the name of the kanji from which the radical is derived.　Then I tried to use the japanese name for them, such as risshinben (as in 快)　and shitagokoro (as in 志), hoping that the  hiragana or katakana input would recognize them and propose me their representation, but it did not work.

So I looked into the Full Japanese Character Table, under the "by radical" tab, and found at  least a version of each of them : 忄 (CJK 5FC4) and 㣺 (CJK 38FA) with the correct kun readings. I have them now as favorites but do I need to do that for all radicals? Do I need to register all of them in a user dictionary?  I would imagine that I am not the only one who wants to do use them.

Besides, the versions I have found are not suited for all occasions: they are centered on a standard kanji square. If I want them to appear near to a placeholder, or demonstrate their proportion to the rest of a typical kanji, I have to make complicated adjustments, depending on my use and the kind of radical.

Comment: A question about usage of a computer is off-topic here even if the question is about Japanese text.  The questions in the same category have been closed as off-topic: [How to write hiragana and katakana in Windows?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/289/how-to-write-hiragana-and-katakana-in-windows), [What's the best utility for identifying kanji?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/8/whats-the-best-utility-for-identifying-kanji)  Voted to close as off topic.

Comment: this is probably better suited on superuser

Comment: @Tsuyoshi I expected this but still feel that this Japanese.SE community would certainly be the most knowledgeable about this question.

Comment: I once had a question about LaTeX and Japanese, I wrote it on Latex SE... So @Tsuyoshi is right, this question is off topic, because it doesn't deal with Language itself but with computers input. :) Voting to close as well...

Comment: @Tsuyoshi and all: I reposted [this question, sligtly edited on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/299847/how-to-easily-input-and-display-isolated-japanese-radicals-on-macos-x). Hope I will receive some interesting answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone collected those with unicode points.

> http://shimapucchi.blog93.fc2.com/blog-entry-321.html
>   http://tokyo.cool.ne.jp/kondo_hiro/proverb/busyu/busyu.htm
>   http://www.efontshop.com/feaddfont/help/busyu_list.htm
>   http://www.kanjijiten.net/radical/index.html  (page is in shift-jis encoding)
>   http://www.kanjikentei.jp/list/bushubetsu/

or some at wikipedia

> [http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/部首](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%83%A8%E9%A6%96)